# Grammatical form of "except in"

Tags: grammar

The sentence is this, "English is not spoken anywhere except in the highest echelons of local government."

Does "except" function as the preposition and head of the prepositional phrase, with "in the highest echelons of local government" functioning as the prepositional complement? Or is "except in" a compound preposition?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you call *except in* a compound preposition, I think you need to call *except on*, *except by*, *except with*, etc. complex prepositions. It's much simpler to say *except* can function as the head of the prepositional phrase.

Comment: But note that the phrase *except for* needs to be classified as a complex preposition because it behaves differently from *except in*, etc. Surprisingly, it didn't always. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=except+by%2Cexcept+in%2Cexcept+for%2Cexcept+at&year_start=1650&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexcept%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cexcept%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cexcept%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cexcept%20at%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Note that _anywhere_ is a restricted equivalent to _any place_, and that the example sentence is equivalent to _not spoken (in) any place except for (places) in the highest echelons_. You can't do that with _anywhere_ because it won't allow conjunction reduction of _place(s)_ under identity.

Answer (score -2):

I think that the sentence should read: English is not spoken anywhere except for in the highest echelons of local government.

Comment: No it shouldn't. "except for" needs to be followed by a [noun](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/except-or-except-for?q=except+for), not a preposition.